# Does Weblogic support failover of session objects that are not marked as serializable?

Tags: java, serialization, replication, weblogic, websphere

Working on a lift and shift of a spring MVC app from Weblogic to Websphere.  The previous owners swear that they had failover working, but half of the objects that are stored on the session are not even serializable.

Does Weblogic silently ignore serialization errors these or perhaps does it gracefully treat any non serializable objects in a transient manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does Weblogic silently ignore serialization errors these or perhaps does it gracefully treat any non serializable objects in a transient manner?

To my knowledge, WebLogic doesn't ignore non-serializable object when session replication is activated and the session replication will just fail. WebLogic logs about this using the following message:

```
<Error> <Cluster> <BEA-000126> <All session objects should be serializable to replicate. Check the objects in your session. Failed to replicate non-serializable object.>
```

I can't confirm that right now but [this article](http://weblogic.sys-con.com/node/44435) even claims that session replication would even stop after that.

#### References

- [Configuring Session Persistence](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/webapp/sessions.html#wp139726)